# Is it possible to have dental sealants removed permanently?

Tags: dentistry, removal, enamel

I'm interested in whether it's possible to have dental sealants (on the back molars) removed (and not replaced).

I've heard from (possibly not-credible sources) that acid used when applying (possibly taking off?) the filling etches the enamel on the teeth. Thus, once you get sealants you must always have sealants.

Is this true?

Comment: This is an interesting question. What would be interesting is knowing how fast the decalcified (etched) area recalcifies.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the sealant, [probably the most effective way to protect the teeth from caries](http://jada.ada.org/article/S0002-8177(16)30473-1/fulltext), you need to reapply an acid or remove the superficial sealed enamel. In both cases you will loss more healthy enamel than sealant.

So, I **would not** reccomend to remove a sealant from a sealed tooth, instead, I would **reccomend to re-seal** any partial loss sealed tooth to [avoid the risk of caries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19149298).

By the way, the sealants work creating a barrier between the surface of tyour tooth and the acid that generates the sugar that you drink/eat and is metabolized by normal bacteria living in our mouth.